# Removing Related Objects from Database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

This is my first question on this site. I am teaching myself MVC and Entity Framework in an ASP.Net web app. I have a series of related entities and when I call context.saveChanges() the removed related data items do not get removed.

My Entities
I have an Item Entity that can have 0 to Many Aliases. This was database first project and most of these lines of code have been auto generated.

```
public Class Item
{
  public int Id{get;set};
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public virtual ICollection<AliasClass> AssociatedAliases {get;set;}
}

public Class AliasClass
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int ItemId {get;set;}
  public string AliasName {get;set;}

  public virtual Item RelatedItem {get;set;}
}
```

Ok, we are done with the autogenerated stuff. My Postback action accepts a postback viewmodel. I am implementing repository pattern. And my Item Repo has an update function.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit (Models.EditViewPostBack MyPostBackModel)
{
  If (!ModelState.isValid){
    ... rebuild and copy  // this part works. Skipping over it
  }

  // this may be a key line of my issue
  MyPostBackModel.Item.Alias = MyPostBackModel.myAliases;
  ItemRepo.Update(MyPostBackModel.Item);
  return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Here is Models.EditViewPostBack. The new list of associations get passed back as an array. New associations have an id of 0. At update it will be assigned a real Id.

```
    public class EditViewPostBack{
      Item myItem {get; set;}
      AliasClass[] myAliases {get;set;}
    }
```

Now, finally the meat of the project and my real issue.  This is the method from the ItemRepo that is supposed to update changes.

```
    public void Update (Item myItem)
    {

      // myItem.AssociatedAliases contains only the wanted associations. 
      // It doesn't have the to-be deleted items. 
      // new items have an id of 0

      // defined in class constructor. 
      context.Item.Attach(myItem);
      context.Entry(Item).State = EntityState.Modified;
      foreach(var name in myItem.AssociatedAliases){
        // finds the modified local version of the item. doesn't connect
        // to the database to location info.
        if(name.id > 0)
        {
          var moded = context.AliasClass.find(name.Id); 
          context.Entry(moded).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
        else
        {
          // it is brand new
          context.Item.Add(name)
        }
      }          
      //
      // Once the alias is not attached to it's item it has to go
      // How to handle deletes goes here
      //
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Becuase the entitystate isn't marked as deleted the association remains and the item appears like I never removed it. I have already tried several things.

If i load or search the for the original item with a context.Alias.linqFunction()the entire list is re-associated with the myItem parameter since the id's match.

```
// invoking the following line causes Item.Alias to fully re-associate.
// I lose the list passed to the function 
context.AliasClass.Where(x=>x.ItemId == myItem.Id)
```

I currently cannot load an Alias because that would be a round trip to the database where I am not deleting the item.

I think I need a way to Remove except where Id's match the still connected list. But remove takes an instance of the item to remove.

What can I do to delete these associated Alias names from my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because of having three situation for `Aliases`
. They maybe are new and or edited or mixed. So for handling that you first need to handle `Aliases` change separated than `Item` For doing this create new `Alias[]` and then do this:

```
    foreach(var name in myItem.Aliases){
             if it is edited one: update it
             if it is new one: save it with id of myItem
             }
```

Then before updating `myItem`, just put:

```
    myItem.Aliases=null;
```

If you have some deleted `Aliases`, you can't count on EF inelegance to handle deleting them as you so on adding new ones. You need to delete them by yourself.
So should have something like

```
allAliases=context.Getall(Aliases).where(they are for current item);
```

Then you can have

```
foreach(var aliase in allAliases){
         if it it isnot in myItem.Aliases: delete it
         }
```

For better performance and less complexity, I suggest you first delete all `Aliases` in db and then all your `myItem.Aliases` will be as new ones. So when ever you save your `myItem` all related `Aliases` will be added automatically and you have just two times interaction with db which means better performance.

Comment: This does not work.  Making the myItem.Aliases null just wipes out the association to the item but does not delete them from the datastore.  I need Aliases no longer associated with a Item to get **deleted**. Right now there is a mandatory ItemId in the Aliases table.  But I do see your point about using alias/aliases everywhere. I will update my question to use better names to prevent confusion.

Comment: Thank you, Hadee.  I attempted something like this before but ran into an issue.  Your proposed solution will always make 2 requests to the database.  This seems very inefficient for an update process.  The issue I had previously was as soon as I load the aliases where itemid is the current item all previously existing relationships between item and alias would suddenly appear in item.aliasclass. so then I would loose track of what needed to be added, deleted, or updated.

Comment: I have used your suggestion and have changed my program to pass back the Id's that should be removed.  I had to manipulate the jquery on the site and change up the save code to heck for ID and blank value. ID and value -> save. ID and blank -> delete. No Id and blank -> ignore. No ID value -> add to DB.